# On one page, same person, different reps

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Just out of curiosity and assuming I'm overlooking the obvious, why can the same user have different reputation on the same page?

Page this occurs (at least today, see screenshot) on stackoverflow: [using document() function in .NET XSLT generates error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710369/using-document-function-in-net-xslt-generates-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[image: Same user, different rep]

Comment: User names are not unique.  These are two different users.

Comment: Those were two accounts created by the same person.  The accounts are now merged.

Comment: @M.Tibbits: generic gravatars are generated from ip hashes.  If two users have the same ip, they will have the same gravatar.  A user can have multiple accounts with different generic gravatars, so the inverse (or the inverse inverse?) shouldn't be used as an indication that two accounts aren't the same user...

Comment: @won't - I think you want `CONVERSE`

Comment: @Won't, Ahh, I see that.  I was thinking they were *email-based*.  Good to know!

Comment: @JNK: You sure it isn't the `NEW BALANCE`?

Comment: When you see two different user accounts who *obviously* represent the same person in the future, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and ask for them to be merged.

Comment: @Cody: thanks, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User who asked the question has user id [319426](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319426/simon) and the user who responded to the question has user id [325733](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325733/simon) *(this link no longer exists because the accounts have been merged)*. There is no restriction (uniqueness) forced in user names. Multiple users can have the same name *Jim Bob*.

Those two accounts may or may not be the same person.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740792/ssis-etl-design), the OP name is Siva and I posted an answer to the question. However, I didn't ask the question.

The same gravatar image in your question leads me to believe that the same person created both the user accounts.

Comment: Apparently the dates, the text and the same thread let me to believe that this was indeed the same user. It's probably the same person, but not the same ID, I see that now. Tx.

Answer (score 11):

It may be the same *person*, but it's not the same *user*. Notice the lack of a blue background on the second flair.

What likely happened is that the user was unregistered and their cookie got lost or deleted. So they went and created another account (also unregistered) with the same name.

Comment: Both users are unregistered.

Comment: Ah, I should've seen that. "Missing the obvious", i.e. the color, indeed ;) Tx.